# slave: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found[cluster setup]

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

All the answers to my question was showcased in a single node cluster

But i want the answer in multi node cluster

I had configured all the details of namenode and datanode correctly as in this blog https://www.edureka.co/blog/setting-up-a-multi-node-cluster-in-hadoop-2.X?utm_source=youtube&utm_campaign=hadoop-installation-multi-node-051216-wr&utm_medium=descriptionbut

but I had got stuck at this error!!!

Not able to start datanode
[click here to see error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZwQS.png)

```
slave: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found
```

## slave:

i had configured JAVA_HOME properly in hadoop_env.sh i.e.,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

ssh calls are properly going

```
ssh hduser@slave
```

Comment: Can you post the content of hadoop_env.sh, `ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

Comment: slave or master?

Comment: can you paste slave node

Comment: should both master and slaves had to have the same java paths??

Comment: You can have the different JAVA_HOME between hosts provided you modify the hadoop_env.sh

Comment: [java (both slave and master)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oPzrYIdftJnqf4N34BVQXDshs9fmI9zh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: [hadoop env.sh](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sOSDSM8uLbO8BUkAShrRWieyR1Qxx4v-/view?usp=sharing)